# Python: Find largest number from list, Type error not supported

Tags: python

User will `Input list of numbers` which will always `end when 0 is entered`,

```
output will give largest number and it's occurrences in the list.
```

I have done similar program in java but when i am trying it in python, i am getting error.

Error:

**Input: 123430**

```
Error: if(currentnum>max):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

**Code:**

```
currentnum= input('Enter Numbers List, to end  press 0: ')
max=1
while (int(currentnum)>0):
    if(currentnum>max):
            max=currentnum
            count=1
    elif currentnum==max:
            count+=1
print('The Largest number is:', int(max),'and count is',int(count))
```

Comment: `currentnum > max` needs to be `int(currentnum) > max`

Comment: Do you see how you used `int(currentnum)` when comparing it to `0`?  Do you see how you *didn't* use `int(currentnum)` when you compared it to `max`?  That should give you a clue.  But the real problem is you're dragging it around as a string.  Just convert it to an `int` once, when you first read it.  Then you can get rid of the other `int()` conversions in your code.  You've already seen how error-prone keeping it as a string is.

Comment: And `max = currentnum` needs to be `max = int(currentnum)`. This would all be simpler if you converted the input to an integer immediately when you read it.

Comment: same error when i do: int(currentnum) > max

Comment: @Barmar changed but when i enter numbers no output is displayed

Comment: Also, don't use `max` as a variable name.  `max` is a builtin function which is masked when you do that.

Comment: You ran into an infinite loop as currentnum never gets smaller then 0, if it was larger then 0 at the beginning. Also you dont want to compare your whole input at once, From your given input '123430' it seems like you want to iterate over the _digits_. You can do that easily by interpreting your input as a string first. Loop with a for each of each character. Cast the character to an int.  Compare it to 0 if end. Then compare the **casted** digit to the max and count.

What do you want to achieve with the count? Do you want to know how often the largest digit is present in the input string?

Comment: @Fayakon - you could post another question by making your *requirements* clear!  and the approach you've stuck..